# What pronoun should be used for “She is my guide” as opposed to “He is my guide”?

Tags: pronoms, genre, démonstratifs

I believe that “C'est mon guide” (rather than “Il est mon guide”) is used for “*He* is my guide”.

So how to say, “*She* is my guide”?

Comment: [_Il avait un joli nom, mon guide, Nathalie..._](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTX-eBuDGrE)

Answer (score 5):

You believe wrong,  « **C'est mon guide** » doesn't need to be adapted as it already equally applies to a woman. « Elle est mon guide » is somewhat odd. It matches the unidiomatic « Il est mon guide » unless used in a religious context.

In accordance with titles and jobs ongoing feminisation of and given the fact *guide* is already both masculine and feminine, I might simply say ***C'est ma guide*** just like *C'est ma ministre* ou *ma députée* are commonly used.

---

« **C'est mon guide** » peut déjà très bien s'appliquer à une femme et n'a pas besoin d'être adapté. « Elle est mon guide » me semble un peu lourd, ou du moins d'un autre registre que la formule originale. C'est la version féminisée de « Il est mon guide » qui est peu idiomatique, sauf dans un contexte religieux ou similaire.

Au regard de la féminisation croissante des titres et métiers et sachant que « guide » est déjà épicène, « **C'est ma guide** » ne me choque pas du tout, en tout cas pas plus que « C'est ma ministre » ou « ma députée », et passe beaucoup mieux que l'ambigu « C'est ma maire » ou l'impossible « C'est ma médecine ».

---

Références : [TLFI](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/guide)

> II. − *Subst. fém.*
> A. − [Le subst. désigne une pers.]
> 1. *Rare.* Femme, jeune fille qui dirige la marche de quelqu'un. *Ma jeune guide m'indiqua du doigt, à flanc de coteau, une chaumière qu'on eût pu croire inhabitée* (Gide, *Symph. pastor.*,1919, p. 878).

Voir aussi [cet article](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/guide/38570/difficulte) du Larousse en ligne.

Comment: Malheureusement c'est faux, Par définition : "guide" nom masculin. Ce sera vrai quand les dictionnaires seront mis à jour.

Comment: Les lexicographes ne dictent en rien l'usage. J'ai du mal à voir pourquoi "ma guide" poserait problème de toute façon, d'autant qu'une guide au féminin existe depuis belle lurette pour désigner les membres de certains mouvements de jeunesse comme les Guides Catholiques de Belgique (exclusivement féminin de 1915 à 1979)

Comment: S'il faut un argument d'autorité pour utiliser "guide" au féminin en tant que métier, on peut citer http://www.ladocumentationfrancaise.fr/rapports-publics/994001174/index.shtml#

Comment: Je vous ai précisé ce qui est faux et pourquoi, je vais donc vous l'écrire à nouveau : Le dictionnaire (Larousse en autre) dit que Guide est un nom masculin, donc par définition "ma guide" est faux. Guide au féminin désigne une lanière de cuir qu'on attache au mors d'un cheval

Comment: Autant pour moi, mon dictionnaire doit dater du moyen âge ... dois je supprimer mes commentaires ou les laisser du coup ?

Comment: @Froggiz , en France la plupart (ou même tous) des métiers son féminisés, depuis une vingtaine d'années - même si tous les dictionnaires ne sont pas à jour -. Cela peut être laid, mais pour guide, il n'y a aucun problème.

Comment: @Froggiz - Au temps pour moi : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_temps_pour_moi

Answer (score 4):

« C' » est un pronom démonstratif impersonnel qui signifie « ceci » ou « cela », il peut donc désigner « il » ou « elle ». Pour préciser dans ce cas, vous pouvez utiliser:

> Elle est mon guide.

Au passage « c'est mon guide » doit avoir un contexte, sinon il est difficile pour l'interlocuteur de savoir qui représente « c' »: , « ceci » ou bien « cela ».

---

« C' » is an impersonal demonstrative pronoun meaning « ce », « ceci » or « cela », it can mean « il » or « elle ». To specify, you can use:

> Elle est mon guide.

By the way, « c'est mon guide » has to have a context, otherwise it is difficult to know who is behind « c' »: « ceci » or even « cela ».

Comment: Je pense que "C'est ma guide" serait plus naturel que "Elle est mon guide", si on veut souligner que c'est une femme.

Comment: « C' » est le résultat de l'élision du e final du pronom démonstratif neutre simple « ce » : « C'est mon guide » = « Ce est mon guide ». 
« C' » ne signifie pas « ceci » ou « cela » car ces deux pronoms impliquent une notion de proximité absente ici.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/pro3.html

You can use **"*c'est*" + noun** to replace "*il*" (*= he*) or "*elle*" (*= she*).

"il" / "elle" :

- + adjective alone
- + nationality, occupation, religion, job

Write : "*Elle est mon guide.*"

**Source :**

- FR : http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/fle/c-est-et-il-est-21.php
- EN : https://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/pro3.html